# Toggle button with icon

Tags: java, swing, togglebutton, imageicon

I'm trying to create a toggle button that looks like a playing card. I can't get the image to show up no matter where I put the img folder. I'm using the following code.

```
final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Toggle button test");
frame.setSize(500, 300);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.getContentPane( ).setLayout(new FlowLayout());

ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("img/1.png");
JToggleButton jtbButton = new JToggleButton(icon);

frame.add(jtbButton);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following

```
System.out.println(new File("img/1.png").getAbsolutePath());
```

Then ensure that the folder `img` exists at the location displayed

Aside: Typically you will want to read the image resource from the classpath rather than be dependent on a file location. This is why it is better to read from a resource, For example:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(MyClass.class.getResource("img/1.png"));
```